# Color of a plane in Contourplot3D

Tags: plotting, color

I have the following code example:

```
cylinder = ContourPlot3D[y^2 + z^2 == 32, {x, 0, 5}, {y, -6, 6}, {z, -8, 8}, 
                         Mesh -> 1, ContourStyle -> FaceForm[{White, Red}, Opacity[0.0]], 
                         AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}];
areaR = ContourPlot3D[{1, 0, 0}.({x, y, z} - {0, 1.5, 1.5}) == 0, 
                      {x, 0, 5}, {y, -6, 8}, {z, -6, 8}, 
                      ContourStyle -> Directive[White], Mesh -> False];
Show[cylinder, areaR]
```

[image]

Can anyone tell me how I get the plane `areaR` to be `White`?

Answer (score 4):

The lighting will always introduce deviations from the intended surface color. If you don't want this, you can override the lighting by adding [`Glow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Glow.html) to the color. I'm doing this for the `areaR` object which represents the plane:

```
cylinder = 
  ContourPlot3D[y^2 + z^2 == 32, {x, 0, 5}, {y, -6, 6}, {z, -8, 8}, 
   Mesh -> 1, ContourStyle -> FaceForm[{White, Red}, Opacity[0.0]], 
   AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}];
areaR = ContourPlot3D[{1, 0, 0}.({x, y, z} - {0, 1.5, 1.5}) == 0, {x, 
    0, 5}, {y, -6, 8}, {z, -6, 8}, ContourStyle -> Directive[
     Glow[White]
     ],
   Mesh -> False];
Show[cylinder, areaR,
 Background -> Lighter[Gray],
 Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image: glow]

The options `Background -> Lighter[Gray]` and `Lighting -> "Neutral"` aren't really necessary but I added them for clarity.

Comment: I should have thought about `Glow`, thanks, +1.

Answer (score 1):

It is `White` :)

```
Show[cylinder, areaR, Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image]

Comment: Somehow gray ?! :)

Ok, I understand it is a problem of Show and Lighting. Is there a way to combine both graphs and use different lightings for both objects (Cylinder, areaR).

Something like this for the areaR:
    Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}} 
and for the cylinder
    Lighting->Automatic

Comment: @user8905 I do not think so :/ but I might be wrong.